# How do I pass to service provider which identity provider was chosen by user for authentication?

Tags: authentication, wso2-identity-server

We intend to support multiple identity providers (Google, Facebook, Yahoo, LDAP, ADFS) for user authentication using WSO2 Identity Server. We have a requirement that Service Provider (SP) know which identity provider was chosen by user for authentication. SP and WSO2 IS use SAML.

Is it possible to have some parameter (configured per identity provider) to be returned by WSO2 to SP (either as claims or query parameter) on successful authentication or every time WSO2 IS redirects user to SP Assertion Consumer URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it in the Service Provider -> Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration. Select option "Always send back the authenticated list of identity providers".

[Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPzKU.jpg)